# CSS seems to be sent to page, but nothing applies [ExpressJS + Handlebars]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am attempting to do a very simple page with Handlebars and Express with NodeJS, however I am running into difficulty getting it to display css. It seems that the browser is receiving the CSS file given the feedback and the 200 code I'm getting in my Node window, but no effect is shown on the actual page.

**file structure**

```
app.js
/public
  /stylesheets
    style.css
/views
  /layouts
    main.handlebars
  home.handlebars
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));


var person = {
  name:"Clay",
  age:"20",
  attr:["tall","handsome","wearing a red sweater"]
}


app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('home', {layout: false, people: person});
});

module.exports = app;
```

**main.handlebars**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Database</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    {{{body}}}

</body>
</html>
```

**home.handlebars**

```
<h1>Example App: Home</h1>

hello world
```

**style.css**

```
body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

**node console**
[image]

Comment: can you try to change app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public'))); to app.use('/public',express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));  and see.

Comment: does not appear to work @xan_z

Comment: Okay, also update the HTML template from <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css" /> to <link rel="/public/stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css" />.. this is what I have and it works. I use ejs thou..